# graph value on a-chart engine for android

Tags: android, achartengine

I am new to android programing.

Can some please guide me how can i get the graph value of specific co-ordinates,

i,e if i click on some points on the graph.

More specifically if my finger taps on any point on the screen of graph,

a label should pop up saying the values of the coordinate.

Please give in suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The name of the library you are using is AChartEngine.
To answer your question, please see an example [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java). Start at line 170.